# GAS UrlFetch Total Bytes Limit

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

I've seen a couple similar questions, but none with the details I'm looking for.

I see a couple bits of information about UrlFetch data quotas:
UrlFetch Total Bytes    100mB / day 100mB / day 100mB / day https://script.google.com/dashboard

and also:
URL Fetch data received 50MB / day  100MB / day 100MB / day https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

I would like to now is the 100MB up, 100MB down, 100MB total? Is this a limit for all traffic, or just a limit per url transmitted to?

The error I am receiving: "UrlFetch failed because too much traffic is being sent to the specified URL."
Seems to indicate this quota is being reached on a per url basis, is that true?

In general is there a place where I can find more in depth information about these Quotas?

Answer (score -1):

For up vs. down vs. total, I believe it is down based on my experience. For up, they have a separate quota called "UrlFetch Post Size" given in this [dasbhoard](https://script.google.com/dashboard).

Regarding too much traffic error, I got the same error for reaching down quota limit (of 100mB/day).